# Syntax error with TYPE(*) with Intel Fortran Compiler 2015 (Mac OS X)

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran

When compiling the following Fortran program using IFORT 2015 (for Mac OS X):

```
MODULE X

    USE, INTRINSIC :: iso_c_binding, ONLY: c_intptr_t

    IMPLICIT NONE

    INTERFACE

        INTEGER(c_int) FUNCTION process(variable) BIND(C, name = "_process")
            USE, INTRINSIC :: iso_c_binding, ONLY: c_int
            !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES NO_ARG_CHECK :: variable
            !GCC$ ATTRIBUTES NO_ARG_CHECK :: variable
            TYPE(*), INTENT(IN) :: variable
        END FUNCTION

    END INTERFACE

END MODULE
```

... it gives the following error:

```
example.f90(13): error #5082: Syntax error, found ',' when expecting one of: , <END_OF_STATEMENT> ; 
TYPE(*),  INTENT(IN) :: variable
-------^
```

This is how I compile the Fortran program (example.f90):

```
ifort example.f90 -free -m64 -c -fPIC -02 -o wrapper.o
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assumed-type declaration `type(*)` is a feature of Fortran 2018 (or TS29113 addition to Fortran 2008) that is first supported by Intel Fortran Compiler in [release 16.0](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-fortran-compiler-160-for-os-x-release-notes-for-intel-parallel-studio-xe-2016#f15).

You should use a later version of the compiler or rewrite the code to avoid using this feature.